# How to keep the sequence in javascript Map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i have myData map as below

```
 var myData =  new Object();

 myData[10427] = "Description 10427";
 myData[10504] = "Description 10504";
 myData[10419] = "Description 10419";
```

but now when i iterate over myData, i don't get same sequnce in chrome and IE works fine in firefox. It iterates in ascending order of key

```
for (var key in myData) {
  alert("key is"+key);
  }
```

i get the output in ascending order in alert as `10419,10427,10504`

How i can make sure to iterate in same order as data as inserted in map?

Comment: Use a string instead of a number. Something like `myDate['10427'] = "Description 10427";`. If you just use a number it gets added at that index in the array.

Comment: @putvande — Nonsense. The value you pass to square bracket notation will be stringified before use. Plain objects are always unordered.

Comment: Ow my bad... I thought the question was about an Array. Misread it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objects are unordered in JS. Use an array if order matters.

```
var myData = [];
myData.push({ "number": 10427, description: "Description 10427" });
```

Comment: i do not want the order i want the same sequence(while iteration) as the sequnce of data insertion

Comment: If you want them in insertion order, then don't sort them.

Comment: i am not sorting them. They are getting automatically in chrome and ie but works fine in firefox

Comment: If you want them in insertion order, then **store them in an array as per this answer** *and* don't sort the array.

Answer (score 60):

ES6 Maps preserves the insertion order.

The set method is used for setting the key value pairs

```
var myData = new Map();
myData.set(10427, "Description 10427");
myData.set(10504, "Description 10504");
myData.set(10419, "Description 10419");
```

Map keys and values are printed using

```
myData.forEach((value,key) => console.log(key, value));
```

This will print the keys and values in the insertion order

Comment: "The Map object holds key-value pairs and remembers the **original insertion order** of the keys."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: `Console.log` it printed insertion order, but while iterating in HTML, it not maintaining the insertion order.